# Select two different date columns from two different tables and group both of the dates by month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm stuck quite hard here and I need some help please! I have two tables which are expense_t and budget_t.

Here's my budget table, this is where parents can have multiple children and assign a budget to them.

***budget_t:***

```
bud_id   bud_date   bud_amount  bud_category   chi_id  par_id
------  ----------  ----------  -------------  ------  ------
  1     2020-03-01      200         Food         1       1
  2     2020-03-01      100     Entertainment    1       1
  3     2020-04-01      200         Food         2       2
  4     2020-04-01      100     Entertainment    3       2
```

Here's my expense table, this is where children spending are recorded.

```
exp_id   exp_date   exp_amount  exp_category   chi_id
------  ----------  ----------  -------------  ------
  1     2020-03-10      50          Food         1   
  2     2020-03-20      50      Entertainment    1  
  3     2020-04-15      20          Food         2   
  4     2020-05-31      50          Food         1
```

What I'm trying to do is, to come out with a line graph with MONTH (such as March) on the X-axis while total bud_amount and total exp_amount for that specific month for a specific child on the Y-axis. For example, line chart for chi_id="1" will look like this:-

[image: Line Chart Graph for chi_d="1"]

I can't seem to grasp the understanding of how the SQL queries work as I am still new to it! But these are the SQL queries that I have tried but did not work. The 3rd query seems to work but only on one table.. I have no idea how to combine both of the tables together.

```
SELECT exp_date, DATE_FORMAT(exp_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS month, sum(exp_amount) AS expense, sum(bud_amount) AS budget FROM expense_t INNER JOIN budget_t ON
expense_t.chi_id=budget_t.chi_id WHERE (exp_date BETWEEN "2019-04-07" AND "2020-04-07") AND expense_t.chi_id="1" GROUP BY month ORDER BY month // the sum for both amounts went crazy

SELECT exp_date, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM exp_date) AS month, sum(exp_amount) AS expense, sum(bud_amount) AS budget FROM expense_t INNER JOIN budget_t ON
expense_t.chi_id=budget_t.chi_id WHERE (exp_date BETWEEN "2019-04-07" AND "2020-04-07") AND expense_t.chi_id="1" GROUP BY month ORDER BY month // the sum for both amounts went crazy too

SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM exp_date) AS month, sum(exp_amount) AS expense FROM expense_t WHERE (exp_date BETWEEN "2019-04-07" AND "2020-04-07")
AND chi_id="1" GROUP BY month ORDER BY month // the sum and month are perfectly fine but no idea how to                                             combine with budget_t table.
```

Wanted results from SQL queries (total budget and expense for specific month (taken from date) for a specific chi_id:-

```
month   total_budget  total_expense  chi_id
-----   ------------  -------------  ------
March       300           100          1   
April         0             0          1  
May           0            50          1
etc...
```

Here is my PHP code:-

```
<?php
include('conn.php');
if (!isset($c_id)) {
  $c_id = $_GET['c_id'];
}
$sql = "Please-help-me!";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<=0)
{
  die("<script>alert('Sorry, there is not info to generate chart. Please try again after you have recorded more expenses!'); window.history.go(-1);</script>");
}
else
{
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Date', 'Budget', 'Expense'],
        <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
          echo "['".$row["month"]."', '".$row['budget']."', '".$row['expense']."'],";
        }
        ?>
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Budget-Expense Line Chart for <?php echo "$user" ?>',
        curveType: 'function',
        pointSize: 10,
        legend: { position: 'right' }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
  <?php
}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: You've included a lot already. Thank you. Can you show your desired output from the SQL query? Which MySQL version do you have `SELECT VERSION()` as query?

Comment: I have now added my desired output in my question, I am not sure about 'SELECT VERSION()' but here are my versions: phpMyAdmin 4.8.6, MySQL 5.7.26 and PHP 7.2.18

Comment: great. the 5.7.26 was the bit I was after. Please test @Akina's solution and mark it correct if it works for you.

Comment: Hey Dan! The query did work exactly like the results i wanted (p.s. i tweaked it a bit to suit my graph)  [link](https://imgur.com/EfTtJYR ) Thanks a lot! But then when i ran the same query in my PHP codes the first row of the data went missing like this  [link](https://imgur.com/undefined)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT year_and_month, 
       SUM(total_budget) total_budget,
       SUM(total_expense) total_expense,
       chi_id
FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bud_date, '%y-%m') year_and_month,
              SUM(bud_amount) total_budget,
              0 total_expense,
              chi_id
       FROM budget_t
       GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bud_date, '%y-%m'),
                chi_id

       UNION ALL

       SELECT DATE_FORMAT(exp_date, '%y-%m'),
              0,
              SUM(exp_amount),
              chi_id
       FROM expense_t
       GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(exp_date, '%y-%m'),
                chi_id
     ) total
GROUP BY year_and_month, 
         chi_id
```

Comment: Thanks Akina! The query did work exactly like the results i wanted (p.s. i tweaked it a bit to suit my graph) [SQL Result](https://imgur.com/EfTtJYR) Thanks a lot! But then when i ran the same query in my PHP codes the first row of the data went missing like this [1st Row Missing](https://imgur.com/TehDM59)

Comment: @JuanOhJuan *But then when i ran the same query in my PHP codes* I cannot help - I don't use PHP. Create new topic.